# Selection Criteria for Top Tier Participants in the Tata Steel Chess Tournament

Tags: tournament, grandmaster, tata-steel

I'm curious about the process of selecting participants for the top tier (Masters) of the Tata Steel Chess Tournament, held annually in Wijk aan Zee, Netherlands. This prestigious event attracts some of the world's best chess players. I'm interested in understanding the criteria or the selection process used to invite these top-tier players each year.

Is the selection based on world rankings, previous performances in other tournaments, invitations, or a combination of these factors? Also, are there specific qualifications that players need to meet to be considered for the Masters section of the Tata Steel Chess Tournament?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chessbase has an [interesting article](https://en.chessbase.com/post/coming-soon-the-tata-steel-tournament-2024-in-wijk-aan-zee) which gives some details:

> **Anyone who wins a tournament below the Masters can move up a division the following year**. This is how Alexander Donchenko slipped into the Masters 2024 after winning the Challengers last year.
>
> **The other players are invited**, and once again Jeroen van den Berg's team will ensure a special mix. **Some of the absolute top players will be playing, the Dutch top players, but also up-and-coming talents**. ...
>
> Ding Liren is back at the chessboard ...
>
> Ian Nepomniachtchi and Alireza Firouzja, ranked fifth and sixth in the world respectively, will also be playing. **Anish Giri, Jorden van Foreest and Max Warmerdam will represent the host nation**. Praggnandhaa, Vidit and Gukesh will represent the motherland of chess.
>
> Parham Maghsoodloo, Nodirbek Abdusattorov and Wei Yi represent the Asian continent. In recent years there have been very few Chinese men in the top tournaments, why? Reigning Women's World Champion Ju Wenjun will be the only woman in the Masters field.

So, the previous year's Challenger's winner gets an automatic place and then they select a mix of top world players, top Dutch players and then strong young players.